# Issue about showTextAligned (iTextPdf)

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I try to insert a string with Column Text, but it give me an error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -14667

In ColumnText.class -> showTextAligned(...) i see:

```
switch (alignment) {
            case Element.ALIGN_LEFT:
                llx = 0;
                urx = 20000;
                break;
            case Element.ALIGN_RIGHT:
                llx = -20000;
                urx = 0;
                break;
            default:
                llx = -20000;
                urx = 20000;
                break;
        }
```

This means that column must have width and height = 20 000. What can I do if I want to work with a smaller document (i.e. 560px x 300px)?

Full stack trace is:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -14667  at
>   com.sun.pdfview.font.ttf.GlyfTable.getGlyph(GlyfTable.java:57)    at
>   com.sun.pdfview.font.TTFFont.renderCompoundGlyph(TTFFont.java:248)    at
>   com.sun.pdfview.font.TTFFont.getOutline(TTFFont.java:177)     at
>   com.sun.pdfview.font.CIDFontType2.getOutline(CIDFontType2.java:270)
>     at com.sun.pdfview.font.OutlineFont.getGlyph(OutlineFont.java:130)
>     at com.sun.pdfview.font.PDFFont.getCachedGlyph(PDFFont.java:308)    at
>   com.sun.pdfview.font.PDFFontEncoding.getGlyphFromCMap(PDFFontEncoding.java:155)
>     at
>   com.sun.pdfview.font.PDFFontEncoding.getGlyphs(PDFFontEncoding.java:115)
>     at com.sun.pdfview.font.PDFFont.getGlyphs(PDFFont.java:274)     at
>   com.sun.pdfview.PDFTextFormat.doText(PDFTextFormat.java:269)  at
>   com.sun.pdfview.PDFParser.iterate(PDFParser.java:752)     at
>   com.sun.pdfview.BaseWatchable.run(BaseWatchable.java:101)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

My code is:

```
        Document document = null;
    document = new Document(new Rectangle(LABEL_WIDTH*LABEL_RESOLUTION, LABEL_HEIGHT*LABEL_RESOLUTION)); 

    long dateTime = new Date().getTime();
    File pdfTemp = new File(PDF_TEMP_FOLDER, String.valueOf(dateTime) + ".pdf");
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfTemp));

    document.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
BaseFont font = BaseFont.createFont("/ARIALUNI.TTF",
            BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);


    Font arabicFont = new Font(font);



    ColumnText columnText = new ColumnText(cb);
    columnText.setSimpleColumn(0, 0, LABEL_WIDTH*LABEL_RESOLUTION, LABEL_HEIGHT*LABEL_RESOLUTION); 
    columnText.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
    Phrase phrase = new Phrase(nameVisitor + "22", arabicFont);
    columnText.addElement(phrase);
    columnText.go();
document.close();
    writer.close();
```

Comment: *but it give me an error:* - please provide the full stack trace, at least as far as itext classes are involved.

Comment: *com.sun.pdfview.font.ttf.GlyfTable.getGlyph(GlyfTable.java:57)* - This is totally unrelated to the -20000 and 20000 values you found. It more looks like the sun pdfviewer has some trouble reading some glyph information from a font. Have you tried embedding the ARIALUNI font (i.e. using `BaseFont.EMBEDDED`)?

Comment: Yes, I tried. With just PdfContentByte it works great.
cb.beginText();
//  cb.setFontAndSize(font, 24);
//  cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, nameVisitor , 260, 120, 0);
//  cb.endText();

But in this way I can't use RTL text.

Comment: Can you provide a sample PDF generated by your code making the sun pdfviewer fail?

Comment: The problem is that after application fail (v. stack trace) the output pdf has the needed size, but it is empty. If I try to attach an image into content byte directly I see just this image but no text from ColumnText.

Comment: As mkl indicates, the exception isn't thrown by iText, but by something in the `com.sun.pdfview.*` package which isn't part of iText. You also tagged the PDF with the pdf-generation label, but it isn't the PDF generation that goes wrong, according to your stack trace, the problem is caused by the PDF parsing using SUN's PDF viewer *preceding* the PDF creation using iText.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if I change the algorithm of creating PDF document (without ColumnText, just within PdfContentByte) it works fine! Without any troubles in sun.pdfview.*.